# Ebean inheritance "Abstract class with no readMethod" exception

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I try to use inheritance with Ebean in Play! Framework 2.1.0. The inheritance strategy is "single table", as it is the only one supported by Ebean. I closely follow example from [JPA Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_single_table_inheritance_annotations)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="price_type")
@Table(name="prices")
public abstract class Price {
    
    @Id
    public long id;

    // Price value
    @Column(precision=2, scale=18)
    public BigDecimal value;

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
public class FixedPrice extends Price {

    // NO id field here        
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("V")
public class VariablePrice extends Price {
    
    // NO id field here
    ...
}
```

This code passes compilation, but I get

```
RuntimeException: Abstract class with no readMethod for models.Price.id
com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.ReflectGetter.create(ReflectGetter.java:33)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setBeanReflect(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1353)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1142)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1058)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:565)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:252)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:124)
    com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:210)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:64)

 com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:59)

 play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:79)
```

Google search brings [only one relevant link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.0/com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/deploy/ReflectGetter.java) which is source code of ReflectGetter.java. The comment there says

> For abstract classes that hold the id property we need to use reflection to get the id values some times.
>
> This provides the BeanReflectGetter objects to do that.

If I drop `abstract` keyword from superclass declaration, exception disappears. I would really prefer not to make superclass concrete though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add getter/setter for your id field and it will go away.

Comment: I should've thought of that. Thanks!